# Kafka on Kubernetes in minikube not working

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kcat

I am trying to setup Kafka on Minikube, a very basic setup. I can't validate if Kafka and Zookeeper have been setup correctly because `kafkacat` fails.

Here is my config:

**zookeeper**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo1
          image: digitalwonderland/zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zoo1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zoo1
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-1
spec:
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
    - name: follower
      port: 2888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: leader
      port: 3888
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-1
```

**kafka**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker0
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: wurstmeister/kafka
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: kafka-service
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zoo1:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      name: kafka-port
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"
```

**pods**

```
kafka-broker0-6885746967-6vktz            1/1     Running   0          5m20s
zookeeper-deployment-1-7f5bb9785f-7pplk   1/1     Running   0          5m25s
```

**svc**

```
kafka-service          ClusterIP      10.99.226.129    <none>           9092/TCP                                    6m30s
zoo1                   ClusterIP      10.96.140.187    <none>           2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP                  6m35s
```

**kafkacat logs**

```
✗ kafkacat -L -b kafka-service:9092 -d broker
%7|1596239513.610|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1596239513.610|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1596239513.610|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1596239513.610|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.4.0 (0x10400ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, CC CXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2)
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1596239513.610|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1596239513.610|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596239513.610|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596239513.614|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap: failed: err: Local: Host resolution failure: (errno: Bad address)
```

**NODEPORT UPDATE**

✗ kafkacat -L -b kafka-service:30236 -d broker

```
%7|1596476848.078|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-service:30236/bootstrap]: kafka-service:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> DOWN
%7|1596476848.078|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 46ms: application metadata request
%7|1596476848.078|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 46ms: application metadata request
%7|1596476849.065|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Cluster connection already in progress: application metadata request
%7|1596476849.065|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure
```

**minikube ip**
✗ kafkacat -L -b 192.168.64.2:30236 -d broker

```
|1596476908.164|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap]: 192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1596476908.164|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: 192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1596476908.164|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.4.0 (0x10400ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, CC CXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2)
%7|1596476908.164|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap]: 192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1596476908.164|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap]: 192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1596476908.164|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap]: 192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1596476908.164|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap]: 192.168.64.2:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1596476908.164|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
```

✗ kafkacat -L -b localhost:30236 -d broker

```
%7|1596477098.454|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1596477098.454|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.4.0 (0x10400ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, CC CXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SYSLOG SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2)
%7|1596477098.454|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1596477098.454|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1596477098.454|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596477098.454|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1596477098.454|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596477098.454|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596477098.454|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1596477098.460|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#127.0.0.1:30236 (plaintext) with socket 9
%7|1596477098.461|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: failed: err: Local: Broker transport failure: (errno: Connection refused)
%7|1596477098.461|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> DOWN
%7|1596477098.461|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:30236/bootstrap]: localhost:30236/bootstrap: Broker changed state DOWN -> INIT
%7|1596477098.461|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 43ms: application metadata request
%7|1596477098.461|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 42ms: application metadata request
```

Comment: From where are you running `kafkacat`? because if it's your own workstation, that's why it can't resolve `kafka-service` -- that name only exists within the cluster

Comment: Adding to what @mdaniel , Expose your kafka service ad a Nodeport service , then you should be able to acess from your workstation.

Comment: I am running ```kafkacat``` from local(mac), exposing it as NodePort as the answer below gives errors that I have updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      nodePort: 30236
      name: kafka-port
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"
```

I have never used kafkacat, but if it is a cli that is installed on your host, and not inside of another container, you can use it like this now:

```
✗ kafkacat -L -b localhost:30236 -d broker
```

localhost, or the ip of your kubernetes node.

Using a service default is of type ClusterIp, and this can be accessed only inside the kubernetes cluster

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried this but is failing with errors updated in question.